# Java Stream - group by mutiple field

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List of ServerPricing Object, which i want to group by offeringClass and payment option.
Tried below code , but failing. Advice please

```
 Map<String, List<ServerPricing>> groupByOfferingClassPaymentOption =
            serverPricingList.stream().collect(
                p.getOfferingClass().getOfferingClassMapped()+ p.getPaymentOption().getPaymentOptionMapped(),
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                p -> Arrays.asList(p.getOfferingClass().getOfferingClassMapped(), p.getPaymentOption().getPaymentOptionMapped())));
```

and below is the server pricing class

```
public class ServerPricing implements Serializable {
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date createdDate;
    private LeaseTerm leaseTerm;
    private OfferingClass offeringClass;
    private PaymentOption paymentOption;
    private int serverAttributesId;
    @Transient
    private float price;
}
```

Comment: You could group by a `Map.Entry`.

Comment: Can you give example or some reference please

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> Arrays.asList(p.getOfferingClass().getOfferingClassMapped(), p.getPaymentOption().getPaymentOptionMapped())))` should be sufficient...with a return type `Map<List<Object>, List<ServerPricing>>`... If both of those attributes are `String` and you are good with concatenating for a unique key, you can choose simply `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getOfferingClass().getOfferingClassMapped() + "" + p.getPaymentOption().getPaymentOptionMapped())))` with your current return type.

Comment: You could do `Collectors.groupingBy(
                p -> Map.entry(p.getOfferingClass().getOfferingClassMapped(), p.getPaymentOption().getPaymentOptionMapped())`

Comment: @Naman, Thankyou it gets the expected result. how to update the key as String , instead of array composite key

Comment: @upog The latter part of my comment shall answer that, but depending on the type of the attributes that are used collectively to group the items in the list.

Comment: I want key as `p.getOfferingClass().getOfferingClassMapped() + "" + p.getPaymentOption().getPaymentOptionMapped()` and value as corresponding list of ServerPricing

Answer (score 0):

given

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
```

you could have the following

```
    public static Map<Pair<OfferingClass, PaymentOption>, List<ServerPricing>> getServerPricingMap(
        List<ServerPricing> serverPricingList) {
    return serverPricingList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(serverPricing
                    -> Pair.of(serverPricing.getOfferingClass(), serverPricing.getPaymentOption())));
}
```